# push data index into an array in extjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

let's say if the console.log(response) is

```
{
    responseText : {
      "success":true,
      "code":0,
      "error":null,
      "total":1,
      "data":[
        {
          "DATE":"2018-02-07",
          "1.1":"10","1.2":"3"
        },
        {
          "DATE":"2018-03-04",
          "1.1":"1",
          "1.2":"5"
        }
      ]
    }
};
```

How to push properties `1.1`, `1.2` into an array in extjs. Have to omit the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking can be achieved using JavaScript ES6.

Like this

```
const obj = {
    responseText : {
      "success":true,
      "code":0,
      "error":null,
      "total":1,
      "data":[
        {
          "DATE":"2018-02-07",
          "1.1":"10","1.2":"3"
        },
        {
          "DATE":"2018-03-04",
          "1.1":"1",
          "1.2":"5"
        }
      ]
    }
};

const data = obj.responseText.data;

let myArr = [];
data.map((date) => 
  myArr = [...Object.keys(date).filter(key => key != 'DATE')]);

console.log(myArr)
```